# Oracle Stored Procedure Search

Tags: oracle, search, stored-procedures

I have the following code, and I've been tasked with changing the `'eFrom'` value from `'anonymous'` to `'no-response'`.  I have no idea where the value is stored or how to find it.  Right now, the procedure sends out an e-mail that has a sender value of `'anonymous@mail.com'`.  Does anyone know how I can find the value for `'eFrom'` or what table it is stored in?  I'm currently using Oracle SQL Developer.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL
(eTo IN VARCHAR2,
 eFrom IN VARCHAR2,
 eCC IN varchar2,
 eSubject IN VARCHAR2,
 eMessage IN CLOB) AS
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'alter session set smtp_out_server = ' || chr(39) || 'mail.com' || chr(39);
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender => eFrom,
  recipients => eTo,
  cc => eCC,
  subject => eSubject,
  message => eMessage,
  mime_type => 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eFrom` is not stored anywhere (at least not in the code you posted).  It is a parameter that is passed in to this procedure.  You would need to go to whatever code calls this procedure to see where that code is getting the `eFrom` value (there may, of course, be multiple places that call this procedure each of which gets the value from a different place).  Those places may be other PL/SQL blocks (in which case you can use `dba_dependencies` to track them down.  But they may also be in code that runs outside the database in which case you'd need to dig into that source.

If you are looking for other stored PL/SQL objects that are calling your `SEND_MAIL` procedure

```
SELECT owner, name, type
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_name = 'SEND_MAIL'
   AND referenced_owner = <<owner of procedure>>
```

If you don't have access to `dba_dependencies`, you may be able to use `all_dependencies` or `user_dependencies` instead assuming that you have privileges on the calling procedure or own it.

You could, of course, modify the procedure to simply override the `eFrom` value that is passed in and pass a hard coded `no-response@domain.com` but that seems unlikely to be correct.  You could also modify the code to override the `eFrom` value only if the value passed in is `anonymous@domain.com` but, again, that is unlikely to be the best approach.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for.  What's the proper way to use `dba_dependencies` to track them down?  Is there a simple query?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the to, from, cc, subject and message are passed into the stored proc as parameters.  You can't tell what the values are by looking at the stored proc; you have to go to the code that's calling it to see what it's passing in.

You might have to UPDATE that table to change the eFrom address.